# Include filter after withcolumn Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a column and after that apply a filter but I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Here is the code used:

```
df = (
      spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
     .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start,end))
     .filter(f.col('is_client_plus')==1)
     .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
     .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
     .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1) 
     .withColumn('week', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'YYYY-ww'))
     .withColumn('month', f.date_format(f.date_sub(f.col('date_key'), 1), 'M'))
     .withColumn('local_time',f.from_utc_timestamp(f.col('trx_begin_date_time'),'Europe/Brussels'))
     .withColumn('Hour', f.hour(f.col('local_time')))
     .filter(f.when(f.col('Hour')>= 4) & (f.col('Hour')<= 8))
     )
```

The filter that I'm trying to apply it's related to the opening hours of the client, I want to know only data that took place between `4.00` and `8.00` pm for every friday. So if this filter works maybe I have to include another one for the day of the week.

Any clue about the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you're passing only one parameter (condition) to the `when` function while it requires 2. However, no need to use `when` here, simply use `between`:

```
.filter(f.col('Hour').between(4, 8))
```